# Convert input fields to Json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to get a json result from my input fields.

**Json Result**

```
[{ScheduledVisit: "09/06/2017 12:00 AM", Company: "ABC Corp.", ContactPerson: "Someone"}]
```

The reason for that is because I want it to fit my class of

```
public class ScheduleVisit
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Required")]
    public DateTime ScheduledVisit { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson{ get; set; } 
}
```

I do not want to use the `$("inputForm").serialize();` because I want to learn how to do this manually.

Below is my input form

```
<div class="col_half">
    <input type="text" name="ScheduledVisit" placeholder="Scheduled Visit" class="sm-form-control border-form-control datetimepicker" id="ScheduledVisit" />
</div>

<div class="col_half col_last">
    <input type="text" name="company" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="company" id="company" />
</div>

<div class="col_two_third">
    <input type="text" name="contactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" id="contact" /> 
</div>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: _"I would like to get a json result from my input fields."_ Is requirement to create valid `JSON` from `<input>` `.name` and  `.value`s, or is requirement to create a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make object constructors that resemble your backend code.  Here, I am serializing the inputs into a `scheduleVisit` object.

```js
function scheduleVisit(obj) {
  this.scheduledVisit = obj.scheduledVisit;
  this.company = obj.company;
  this.contactPerson = obj.contactPerson;
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var scheduledVisit = document.getElementById('ScheduledVisit').value;
  var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
  var contactPerson = document.getElementById('contact').value
  var visit = new scheduleVisit({
    scheduledVisit: scheduledVisit,
    company: company,
    contactPerson: contactPerson
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(visit));
});
```

```html
<div class="col_half">
  <input type="text" name="ScheduledVisit" placeholder="Scheduled Visit" class="sm-form-control border-form-control datetimepicker" id="ScheduledVisit" />
</div>

<div class="col_half col_last">
  <input type="text" name="company" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="company" id="company" />
</div>

<div class="col_two_third">
  <input type="text" name="contactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" id="contact" />
</div>

<button id=button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I made a javascript object. What else do you want, yo?

Comment: _"I would like to get a json result from my input fields."_ A JavaScript object is not `JSON`

Comment: Please refer to my latest update (the best update).  I now realize that `JSON` is not A JavaScript object.  I tried to fix the code, but I have not ran any unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate `<form>` `.elements`, set each `.name` and `.value` as property and values of a `FormData()` object which can be submitted to server using `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`, or set properties and values at a JavaScript object which can be passed to `JSON.stringify()`

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

form.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const fd = new FormData();
  const props = {};
  for (let element of form.elements) {
    if (element.type !== "submit") {
      props[element.name] = element.value;
      fd.append(element.name, element.value);
    }
  }
  
  for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
    console.log(key, prop)
  }
  
  const json = JSON.stringify(props);
  console.log(json);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="col_half">
    <input type="text" name="ScheduledVisit" placeholder="Scheduled Visit" class="sm-form-control border-form-control datetimepicker" id="ScheduledVisit" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_half col_last">
    <input type="text" name="company" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="company" id="company" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_two_third">
    <input type="text" name="contactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" id="contact" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am new to website dev. Your solution runs on snippet well but when I copy paste the code to my code in asp, the const and let is not accepted.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Substitute `var` for `const` and `let`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the value of your inputs to an object manually. See below snippet for example. You can then serialize the object into a JSON formatted string.

```js
let obj = {};
obj.ScheduledVisit = document.getElementById("ScheduledVisit").value;
obj.Company = document.getElementById("company").value;
obj.Contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
console.log(obj);
let jsonStringObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(jsonStringObj);
```

```html
<div class="col_half">
    <input type="text" name="ScheduledVisit" placeholder="Scheduled Visit" class="sm-form-control border-form-control datetimepicker" value="testVisit" id="ScheduledVisit" />
</div>

<div class="col_half col_last">
    <input type="text" name="company" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="company" value="testCompany" id="company" />
</div>

<div class="col_two_third">
    <input type="text" name="contactPerson" placeholder="Contact Person" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" value="testContact" id="contact" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript you can do `JSON.stringify(yourInputValu)` to convert any `javascript` object to `JSON`

Comment: How do I go about it, using the JSON.stringify()?

Comment: Simply get the value using dom api and just pass it to JSON.stringify e.g document.getElementById('urInput').value

Answer (score 0):

If your input form is that simple and you don't want a more generic solution, you could do it pretty easily with:

```
function get( id ) { return document.getElementById(id).value; }

var json = JSON.stringify({
    ScheduledVisit: get('ScheduledVisit'),
    Company: get('company'),
    Contact: get('contact')
});
```